# Extending C# Functionality

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to extend C#? Or is it completely closed?

I don't mean `extension methods`, I'm asking about really extending the language, by improving or adding functionality to it?

I know there are .NET reference sources, but that's not enough to compile binaries.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: The Roslyn compiler is open source. Fork it and go nuts. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: The C# language is a specification (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx for the most recent version), you can't add anything to it without it becoming something different.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis A completely new keyword with a new functionality. I know about using aliases but that's not what I want. A simple example would be changing the way the language does integer division. Can I make it return a floating point result by default?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot That's for the MS version, but can I create my own fork?

Comment: @RexGrammer Keep in mind that what you described isn't an extension of C#, it is a clear departure from the C# specification. You are free to implement a language like that - but you're probably not allowed to call it C#, I believe.

Comment: @RexGrammer Be aware that if you *do* do that, unless you have complete control over the computer running the code, you won't be able to run it if you change the IL specification. (For example, changing the `div` OPCode to always return the floating point result rather than the quotient). I suppose, however, you could force the compiler to convert all arguments to floating point types if they're ints for division.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft project "Roslyn" may be the key term you're looking for here. It's a C# and VB.NET compiler that will allow you to extend the language if that's what you'd like to experiment with.

> The .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") provides open-source C# and Visual Basic compilers with rich code analysis APIs.

The source code can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Doing a quick google, I found [this blog post](http://ntrush.blogspot.co.nz/2012/12/extending-c-using-roslyn-project.html) which goes through an example (albeit, this was an old post, so things may have changed).

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for! I've had a hard time searching about it on google because 99% of the results I've gotten are about using aliases or extension methods.

Comment: It helps that the project has nice unique name to help clear through the Google results ... unlike looking for topics on the new "Visual Studio Code" IDE.